# How to export all email out of Evolution?

Tags: evolution

Three years ago, I stopped using `Evolution`. Currently, I go back to `Evolution` when I need to review an old email. I would like to export the old emails out of Evolution and remove Evolution all together.

How can I export emails from Evolution? I found no way to export emails from Evolution to anything at all.   (mbox? maildir? I don't see any way to do this)

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export messages from an Evolution folder:

1. Open the folder in Evolution.
2. Select Edit >> Select All from the menu.
3. Select File >> Save As.
4. Choose the location and file name where you want to save your emails.
5. Give the file an ".mbx" extension, so it's clear that it is an mbox file.
6. Click OK.

Comment: I also found that I could get it in maildir format by importing it into kmail and then using the archive feature in kmail to generate a maildir -- which I then had to reorganize a little bit.