# How to export nested folders out of evolution mail?

Tags: email, evolution

In Evolution mail, I know how to export a single folder with emails into an mbox backup file:  ([How to export all email out of Evolution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472309/how-to-export-all-email-out-of-evolution)).

But how do I export a folder from evolution with nested folders within it?  It only exports the mail inside the top folder when I try.